# Conan profile for Windows throwing errors

Tags: c++, cmake, conan, fmt

I am trying to build a small workable C++ project on Windows OS with Conan and CMake.

I installed conan using pip install conan

I created a profile called conan_common_profile.

I did NOT create a CmakeLists.txt . So far my folder only contains two files (conanfile.txt) and conan_common_profile.

Contents of both are as follows

conanfile.txt

```
[requires]
fmt/8.1.1

[generators]
cmake
```

**conan_common_profile**

```
[settings]
# We are building in Ubuntu Linux
os_build=Windows
arch_build=x86_64

# We are building to Windows
compiler=gcc
# Adjust to the gcc version of your MinGW package
compiler.version=9.2
compiler.libcxx=libstdc++11
build_type=Release
```

when I compile using the following command
(after creating a build directory and cd'ing into it)

```
conan install .. --build=missing --profile ../conan_common_profile
```

I get the following console log

```
Configuration:
[settings]
arch_build=x86_64
build_type=Release
compiler=gcc
compiler.libcxx=libstdc++11
compiler.version=9.2
os_build=Windows
[options]
[build_requires]
[env]

ERROR: fmt/8.1.1: Cannot load recipe.
Error loading conanfile at 'C:\Users\.conan\data\fmt\8.1.1\_\_\export\conanfile.py': Unable to load conanfile in C:\Users\.conan\data\fmt\8.1.1\_\_\export\conanfile.py
  File "c:\users\appdata\local\continuum\anaconda3\lib\imp.py", line 171, in load_source
    module = _load(spec)
```

**Any Idea what I could be doing wrong here? I just wish to create a small toy project to get conan up and running**

Comment: Are you using the latest version of Conan?

Comment: Looks like it was the silliest of all errors